# About pspicture: different fillstyle in \pspolygon

Tags: pspicture

I'm currently working on some graphs using pspicture and I have a very specific requirement.
I have a polygon (`\pspolygon`) to cover an specific area in cartesian plane but I use `\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid](10.4, 2.85)(11.25, 2.85)(11.25, 3.05)(10.4, 3.05)` and the part of `fillstyle=solid` is my problem because I need the color inside the polygon to fade or 'evaporate' to one of its sides, as long as the hatched area is not narrowly bounded but rather shows towards infinity.
I'm sure there must be a style for the `fillstyle` to do what I need, but I have read a little and I have not found the solution.
Thanks!!

Comment: With `tikz` this would be easy. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fade right]
\shade[left color=transparent!0,
right color=transparent!100] (0,0) rectangle (0.8,0.2);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[path fading=fade right,fill=red] plot coordinates {(10.4, 2.85)(11.25, 2.85)(11.25, 3.05)(10.4, 3.05)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. Of course, I am not saying that it is not easy with `pstricks`.

Comment: You can see 34. Gouraud shading in [pstricks-add-doc.pdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add?lang=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the gradient fill-style defined by `pst-slpe`:

```
 \documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pstricks, pst-slpe}

   \begin{document} 

   \begin{pspicture}(10,2.5)(11.75,3.4)
   \psframe[linewidth=0.2pt, fillstyle=slope, slopesteps=250, slopebegin=Tomato, slopeend=Tomato!10!Seashell](10.4, 2.85)(11.25, 3.05)
   \end{pspicture} 

   \end{document}
```

[image]